How to represent similar fields in JSON (same data type), fields vs array of objects
I was thinking about designing payload data in JSON with

Multiple (number) fields which contains similar data (check ones in items array)
Variable number of elements in items array (say one request may contain bag other may not). In that case relevant field in Option 1 would be null to indicate it's absence.

Option 1:
 {
   "name":"my_name",
   "id": 1234, 
   "items" : {
     "number_of_pens":  2,
     "number_of_books": 3,
     "number_of_bags":  1
   }
}

Option 2:
{
   "name":"my_name",
   "id": 1234,
   "items": [
    { 
      "name" : "number_of_pens"
      "value": 2
    },
    { 
      "name" : "number_of_books"
      "value": 3
    },
    { 
      "name" : "number_of_bags"
      "value": 1
    }
  ]
}

I wonder if there is any design principles which makes one of the options superior to other one.
I evaluated in terms of schema change, ease of use in different languages/frameworks and payload size. Keeping a primitive data type seems to be much simple than converting object to/from primitives, but am I overlooking to the problem?

#1 would allow you to access myObject.items.number_of_pens directly, whereas #2 would require you to iterate over myObject.items, until you find the one that has name == 'number_of_pens' ...

"Payload size" should not be that much of a relevant criterion these days, I'd say. Actual physical storage is "cheap" these days, and when it comes to sending those payloads via HTTP, compressing the content (deflate/gzip/...) will be able to reduce the "redundancy" of keys being repeated multiple times, quite nicely.
